# Cannot get Microsoft Store ID in the desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure-active-directory

I have done quite a lot of research, trials and errors, yet I am unable to get Microsoft Store ID as described in this tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service

I did this very carefully step-by-step, create azure account, application with secret, associate azure account with client app in partner center.

Both server and client applications are in .NET 7 and I am able to get the OAuth token with the following code, where resource URI is https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/collections.

```
string oauthUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";

var builder = new UriBuilder(oauthUrl);

var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
    { "client_id", clientId },
    { "client_secret", clientSecret },
    { "resource", resourceUri },
};

using var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(builder.ToString(), content);
```

I do receive a successful response with the following structure.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1460404526",
    "resource": "https://service.contoso.com/",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1THdqcHdBSk9NOW4tQSJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3NlcnZpY2UuY29udG9zby5jb20vIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvN2ZlODE0NDctZGE1Ny00Mzg1LWJlY2ItNmRlNTdmMjE0NzdlLyIsImlhdCI6MTM4ODQ0MDg2MywibmJmIjoxMzg4NDQwODYzLCJleHAiOjEzODg0NDQ3NjMsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInRpZCI6IjdmZTgxNDQ3LWRhNTctNDM4NS1iZWNiLTZkZTU3ZjIxNDc3ZSIsIm9pZCI6IjY4Mzg5YWUyLTYyZmEtNGIxOC05MWZlLTUzZGQxMDlkNzRmNSIsInVwbiI6ImZyYW5rbUBjb250b3NvLmNvbSIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZnJhbmttQGNvbnRvc28uY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZGVOcUlqOUlPRTlQV0pXYkhzZnRYdDJFYWJQVmwwQ2o4UUFtZWZSTFY5OCIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiTWlsbGVyIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6IkZyYW5rIiwiYXBwaWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctODkwYS0yNzRhNzJhNzMwOWUiLCJhcHBpZGFjciI6IjAiLCJzY3AiOiJ1c2VyX2ltcGVyc29uYXRpb24iLCJhY3IiOiIxIn0.JZw8jC0gptZxVC-7l5sFkdnJgP3_tRjeQEPgUn28XctVe3QqmheLZw7QVZDPCyGycDWBaqy7FLpSekET_BftDkewRhyHk9FW_KeEz0ch2c3i08NGNDbr6XYGVayNuSesYk5Aw_p3ICRlUV1bqEwk-Jkzs9EEkQg4hbefqJS6yS1HoV_2EsEhpd_wCQpxK89WPs3hLYZETRJtG5kvCCEOvSHXmDE6eTHGTnEgsIk--UlPe275Dvou4gEAwLofhLDQbMSjnlV5VLsjimNBVcSRFShoxmQwBJR_b2011Y5IuD6St5zPnzruBbZYkGNurQK63TJPWmRd3mbJsGM0mf3CUQ",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAv YNqmf9SoAylD1PycGCB90xzZeEDg6oBzOIPfYsbDWNf621pKo2Q3GGTHYlmNfwoc-OlrxK69hkha2CF12azM_NYhgO668yfcUl4VBbiSHZyd1NVZG5QTIOcbObu3qnLutbpadZGAxqjIbMkQ2bQS09fTrjMBtDE3D6kSMIodpCecoANon9b0LATkpitimVCrl PM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4rTfgV29ghDOHRc2B-C_hHeJaJICqjZ3mY2b_YNqmf9SoAylD1PycGCB90xzZeEDg6oBzOIPfYsbDWNf621pKo2Q3GGTHYlmNfwoc-OlrxK69hkha2CF12azM_NYhgO668yfmVCrl-NyfN3oyG4ZCWu18M9-vEou4Sq-1oMDzExgAf61noxzkNiaTecM-Ve5cq6wHqYQjfV9DOz4lbceuYCAA"
}
```

I take the **access_token** value from the response and send this to my client application as **serviceTicket** in the **GetCustomerCollectionsIdAsync**.

```
WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(_context, platformHandle.Handle);
var collectionsId = await _context.GetCustomerCollectionsIdAsync(serviceTicket, publisherUserId);
```

The result is empty string without any error, so I did not know where to look further.

I have tried to shuffle the parameters, pass null or empty strings, but nothing works. I have tried different windows SDK versions from 10.0.17763 to 10.0.22000. From the Azure portal I have found a different version of OAuth tokens v2, which I thought was the successor of the original endpoint with just the documentation missing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

```
string oauthUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

var builder = new UriBuilder(oauthUrl);

var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
    { "client_id", clientId },
    { "client_secret", clientSecret },
    { "scope", $"{resourceUri}/.default" },
};
```

The result was the same - I do get the token, but the client API returns empty string. I really don't know where to look further - it may be just a small tweak in the manifest or partner account setting, but I have rechecked this so many times.

Any ideas how to find out the reason of the errors?